# Why is my header not fixed to the column.

Tags: html, css

Why is my `header` not `fixed` to the `column`.

```
<div class="container-fluid full-ht">
    <div class="row full-ht">
        <div class="col-sm-4 full-ht">
          <div class="patient-column full-ht">
            <div class="fixed-header">
              Fixed Header
            </div>
            Some content follows
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want my `header` to be fixed inside the `column` when the `vertical-scrolling` happens. 
http://www.bootply.com/tducyvW5u1

Comment: `position:fixed`? Please provide your css.

Comment: @sharf click the link provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use

`position:fixed`.

for fixed header,to achieve fixed header while scrolling

**CSS**

```
.fixed-header {
position: fixed; // changed position:absolute to fixed
width: 100%;
top: 0;
padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: I don't see scroll-bars to my column here... http://www.bootply.com/tducyvW5u1# to see whether the header is fixed...

Comment: @theJava : just remove the 'overflow-y:hidden' and 'overflow:hidden'

Comment: @theJava: if you remove the 'overflow:hidden' property from the css,you could see the scrollbar

Comment: That's the scroll-bar for the entire page... i want the scroll-bar the column out there.

Comment: @theJava: just give height in pixels instead of 100% and remove overflow

Comment: I need the column to have its own scroll with a height of 100%... it should be an individual scroll.. any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS I would add `!important` and make the `absolute` a `fixed` as well as make it a priority.

```
.fixed-header {
  position: fixed; !important
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}
```